# Material-UI Dialog(/Modal) by clicking TextField loses focus on every onChange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog

```html
<List key={"test1"} style={{ marginBottom: '10px' }}>
                  <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-basic"
                    key={categoryData.title}
                    label="Title"
                    name="title"
                    value={categoryData.title}
                    type="name"
                    variant="filled"
                    style={{ width: "130ch" }}
                    onChange={(e)=>{
                      setCategoryData({...categoryData,
                        title:e.target.value})
                        console.log(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />
                </List>
```

**Material-UI Dialog(/Modal) by clicking TextField loses focus on every onChange**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17vYYnOQQNFpaki0zi-emvghAbOImykZt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello Navnath kumbhar, I need to see all your code to tell your problem (especially the modal one)

Comment: also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, The problem was, I was defining a component inside of another component.

You can define functions inside of functions. And since my components are just functions, it makes since that you should be able to define one function component inside another function component.

But it won’t work.

You can define a component-like function inside of another component, like this:

```
const renderHeader = (x) => { return <div>{x}</div> }
```

renderHeader is simply a function that returns some JSX. It is not, strictly speaking, a react component. You can totally define that dude inside another function component and it works like a charm.

But make two tiny subtle changes, like this:

```
const RenderHeader = (props) => { return <div>{props.x}</div> }
```

Now, it’s a real component. And Boom!! Now you get crazy “losing focus” behavior.

To fix this, I simply moved the the RendorHeader function to be a top-level function and that fixed it.